# Why does the below code run without an error when both overlapping fields are used?

Tags: c#

The below code runs without an error but the result is erroneous(it gives 8). Why not it throws a compile time/run time error? If it's not throwing error how it's calculating `v.a+v.b` ?

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
internal struct SomeValType
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public  int a; // The a and b fields overlap each
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public  int b; 
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SomeValType v = new SomeValType();
        v.a = 2;
        v.b = 4;
        Console.WriteLine(v.a + v.b);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: why would it give a compile time error? syntactically there is nothing wrong with the code.

Comment: I realised that...Thanks.. It's basically making v.a=v.b=4 and that's why output is coming 8...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer:** the program is computing `v.a + v.b` the usual way.

**Long answer:** `v.a` and `v.b` reside in the same memory location (their addresses are the same). Assigning a value to `v.a` results in the same value being assigned to `v.b`, and *vice versa*.

Therefore, `v.a = 2` assigns `2` to both `v.a` and `v.b`, and the subsequent `v.b = 4` assigns `4` to both `v.b` and `v.a`.

From there, `v.a + v.b` results in `4 + 4`, which gives `8`.

There is no compile-time error because what the code is doing is completely legal. You have explicitly specified that both fields have to reside in the same memory location, so the compiler obliges. It cannot determine that the resulting behavior is not what you wanted in the first place.

Comment: yes...I realised that after posting the question..Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I realised that as the memory address of both fields overlap, their value remains same and that's why the result is the twice of the last assigned field (v.b).

> I initially thought that the purpose of using overlapped fields is to
>   use only one of them and if I try to use the other one also, an error
>   should be thrown.

```
        SomeValType v = new SomeValType();
        v.a = 2;
        v.b = 4      ;
        Console.WriteLine(v.a); // the value is 4
        Console.WriteLine(v.b); // the value is 4
        Console.WriteLine(v.a + v.b); //the sum=4+4=8
        Console.ReadLine();
```